# What is the correct path video using Streamio FFMPEG on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, rubygems

I follow this gem https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg , then I do this :

```
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("#{Rails.root}/public/aaa.mov")
```

but the result is :

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ffmpeg -i /home/user/projects/test/public/aaa.mov
```

Does anyone know ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the `aaa.mov` exists in that path? Do you have `ffmpeg` installed?

Comment: yes, I already check it with :  print File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/public/aaa.mov") and the result TRUE

Comment: `ffmpeg`? is it installed?

Comment: yes, working now, tanks HungryCoder. GBU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gem assumes `ffmpeg` is available in your `PATH`. If it is not in your `PATH`, You need to specify the path of the `ffmpeg` binary.

```
FFMPEG.ffmpeg_binary = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
```

If you don't have `ffmpeg` install, you need to install it.

[Download Page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Comment: Just Up the arrow or check the tick on the left side of my answer. here is how http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @HungryCoder which file do you declare this new path in?  My path is '/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg'. Thanks A

Comment: where should i add this path?